# Counting # of index of undefined char array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to count the number of indexes of an undefined char array which is used as a parameter in the function.

I am already aware that if my array was fixed I can use "sizeof", which isn't the case here.

Attempt:

```
int counting(char *name3) {
  int count = 0;
  int i;

  //I have no idea what to put as my condition nor do I believe 
  //I am approaching this situation correctly...
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(name3); i++) {
      if (name3[i] != '\0') {
        count++;
      }
  }
return count;
}
```

Then if it is run by the following code

```
int main(void) {
char *name = "Lovely";
int x = counting(name);
printf ("The value of x = %d", x);
```

Prints: The value of x = 0

Any help or pointers would be amazing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Two problems: First of all the `sizeof` of a pointer is the size of the *pointer*, not what it points to. To get the length of a string use `strlen`. Second problem is that if you use `strlen` on a null-terminated string, then the length does not include the terminator and your condition will never be true.

Comment: Are you trying to invent `strlen`? If so, it's merely `while(str[count] != '\0') count++;`.

Comment: And a much bigger third problem: If you pass an partially uninitialized array to the function (together with the size to know its length), then the uninitialized data is *indeterminate*, and could be seen as random or "garbage" data. There's no rule that uninitialized data should have a specific value.

Comment: does your count variable in counting function gets incremented? you can use strlen(name3) to find the lentgh of the char array! and you also don't need to check the end of string if you use strlen(name3), hope that it helps you!

Comment: What output do you expect? Do you want to stop counting at \0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i=0;
    char *name = "pritesh";
    for(i=0;;i++)
    {  
        if(name[i] == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

This should work

> note: this might be syntactically incorrect as I have not had my hands on c since a long time

Comment: Or may be like this - `for (i = 0; name[i]; i++){}`.

Comment: Thank you! There were syntax errors, but I was able to get my code running following the format you provided and adding some edits. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In C, Every string ends with '\0' (Null Character)
You can iterate until you meet the Null Character

The example code would be like this

```c
char* name = "Some Name";
int len = 0;
while (name[len] != '\0') {
    len++;
}
```

Also, if it is a char pointer, not char array, `sizeof(char*)` will always return 4 in 32-bit application and return 8 in 64-bit application (the size of the 'pointer' itself - the memory address size)

Comment: "`sizeof(char*)` will always return 4" unless on a system with different size for pointers, like the typical 64-bit system.

Comment: Now you see, it was a decent answer until you presented implementation details as fact. 4 is not the universal sizeof a pointer